# Adding to comments to post: Page not found (404)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

Hi Djangonauts I am new to Django please forgive me if I have silly mistakes in my code and I am currently trying to add comments to my post model

below are my **models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
    message = models.TextField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:single', kwargs={'username': self.user.username, 'slug': self.slug}) 

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comments')
    text = models.TextField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:single', kwargs={'username': self.post.user.username,
                                               'slug': self.post.slug})
```

**views.py 1st attempt**

```
@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect('posts:single', username=comment.author.username, slug=post.slug)

    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        return render(request, 'posts/comment_form.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def remove_comment(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    comment.author = request.user
    post_slug = comment.post.slug
    comment.delete()
    return redirect('posts:single', username=request.user.username, slug=post_slug)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/add_comment/$', views.CommentCreate.as_view(), name='add_comment'),
```

Also I have the urls for FBV below they both give me the same error

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/add_comment/$', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/remove_comment/$', views.remove_comment, name='remove_comment'),
```

**Views.py 2nd attempt**

```
class CommentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ('text',)
    form_class = 'posts/comment_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        slug = self.kwargs('slug')
        print(slug)
        self.object.post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**views.py 3rd try**

```
@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request, slug):
    print(slug)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect('posts:single', username=comment.author.username, slug=post.slug)

    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        return render(request, 'posts/comment_form.html', {'form': form})
```

also changed the urls to

```
url(r'^add_comment/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment'),
```

below is the **PostDetail view and url** they work perfect

```
class PostDetail(SelectRelatedMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    select_related = ('user', 'group')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))   
   #below is the url
 url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='single'),
```

I get the same **error message** as below in all 3 views and also with changed url

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/...
Raised by:  posts.views.PostDetail
```

[image]

Comment: It looks more like a problem with urls.py to me. Can you edit answer with urls.py's please?

Comment: @Bulva if you need any more info than that I have provided in the question please let me know. I added as much information without making the question too long but I would be more than happy to provide any info that could help solve this

Comment: @Bulva also added the urls that I have used in the question above and edited the tags to include Django-urls

Comment: It would be better move slug and pk in the end of the url. For example: url(r'^add_comment/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'views.add_comment_to_post', name='add_comment'). Then if you send a good request on a good url you don't have probably the post with the right slug. You can use print() in views to debug where errors shows.

Comment: For example add print(slug) before post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug) and check the slug. If you will show in the console the slug you know that the problem is line after that print. If there is not a slug in your console you probably send request on wrong url. It is hard to debug without chance to try all the code

Comment: Because the code looks ok and you use function get_object_or_404 which returns 404. So this make sense that if you send a wrong slug or the slug is wrongly parsed from url you are getting 404

Comment: @Bulva I have added the views.py 3rd try. did I do it correct. it is still giving me the exact same error. Please forgive me if I misinterpreted your suggestion I am still learning Django

Comment: No problem. Everyone starts. Just give me some time I will write answer with code and some debugging tips when I will be in the train.

Comment: Are you sure that the slug in the url is correct? Are you able to show the post using that slug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yess!!! got it. There are a few bandages on my head and few cracks on the wall but I finally got it.Thanks a lot to @Bulva for guiding me in the right direction

The **urls.py** should be

```
    url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/add_comment/$', views.CommentCreate.as_view(), name='add_comment'),
```

Since we need both the username of the person posting the comment and also the post where the comment has to be posted. The above url has both

The views.py should be as below

```
class CommentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm #In the second attempt above I used a template name. which is incorrect we should either use a formclass from forms.py or use "fields = text" 

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.author = self.request.user #I used self.object.user instead of self.object.author. since the models call the "user" as "author". I changed this  
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug') #I added the .get without which you get a "'dict' object is not callable" error 
        print(slug)
        self.object.post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Oh yeah last but not the least in your templates. below is how you add the comment button. I'm sure a lot of you smart guys won't need it. but hey doesn't hurt right!!. If you are not using bootstrap remove the "class" from the anchor tag

```
<a class="btn btn-primary comment_button" href="{% url 'posts:add_comment' username=post.user.username slug=post.slug %}">Add Comment</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I expect you have a `urls.py` in your projects where you included `urls.py` for your app (probably named posts). Project `urls.py` probably will look something like this:

```
(r'^posts/', include('project.posts.urls'))
```

Then in your app urls.py you have what have you send to me:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/add_comment/$', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/remove_comment/$', views.remove_comment, name='remove_comment'),
```

I personally this changed to version where slug and primary key will be in the end of the URL, like this:

```
url(r'^add_comment/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment')
url(r'^remove_comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.remove_comment, name='remove_comment'),
```

Then your URL for adding a new comment will look like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/add_comment/how-to-be-a-good-developer/`. The last part of the URL is your slug and you should have a Post with this slug in your database because if you use`get_object_or_404` function and any of your Posts in your will not have the sended slug you will get 404.

**How to very easily debug your code in Django**

You probably run your Django project from console (command-line) with command `python manage.py runserver`. In this console is running a little development server (very same as the others application servers you probably know). If you add `print()` statement to your code, then the output will be send on standard output (in this case to your console where you started development server). So if you send a request on a good URL you can add print statements to easily debug problem. Try something like this:

```
@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request, slug):
    print('I am here in your view')
    print('This is my slug: {}'.format(slug))
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    print('This is my post: {}'.format(post))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect('posts:single', username=comment.author.username, slug=post.slug)

    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        return render(request, 'posts/comment_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Now if you will see in your console `I am here in your view` the Post request was successfully resolved and the view was running. In this time you know that yours `urls.py` are good.

If you will see the message `This is my slug: {your slug from url}` you can check the slug value and check if in your database you have Post with this slug.

The last thing to check. If you will see in `This is my post: {post object}` in your console you know that the Django select the right Post and the problem is in the next code of the view (which I don't expect). If you will see None object or 404 or any error in your console you probably haven't the Post with the slug you sent in your URL in the database.

If you will have questions or you will want discuss some outputs in the console you can write a comment :-)

Comment: Yeah, sorry. That was a mistake. Of course it should look like the second url function. No string but view function

Comment: when I copy & paste the url exact you gave above it gives me below error   
**TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()**you have views in a string `"views.add_comment_to_post"` if I do. `url(r'^add_comment/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment'),` I again get the 404. Nothing is printing in the console. I know how to check console. I have a similar post-like view which has a `print(slug)` in the code that slug is printing. `'I am here in your view'` is not printing either.  I  have upvoted  but still trying to figure what's wrong

Comment: I have added how my url looks in  the address bar in a image above. I think the url is correct

Comment: if `'I am here in your view'` is not printing too what could that mean. I wonder how it reaches the get 404 code without printing the prior 2 print commands

Comment: It has to mean that url resolver didn't find right view. In the error is a posts.view.PostDetail. you don't have this view in your views.py I think so this must be a default view for posts if url is not found in urls.py

Comment: Probably try remove $ in the end of url in function or try delete slug from url if view is called if you remove slug from your url. Then you will know that the problem will be in urls.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170077/discussion-between-samirtendulkar-and-bulva).